# computing the orbits for a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be the Galois group of a field with nine elements over its subfield with three elements. Then the number of orbits for the action of $G$ on the fields with nine elements is

1. 3
2. 5
3. 6
4. 9

I have no idea how to compute the numbers of orbits for a group action. Anyone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the number of fixed points and the order of your group?

Comment: If you like to use a bit more of Galois theory instead, you could look also at the degrees of the minimal polynomials of all elements of $\mathbb{F}_9$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$. The Galois group acts transitively on roots of the minimal polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The Frobenius is an involution on $\mathbb F_9$ with $3$ fixed points (the elements of $\mathbb F_3$).

So what about the orbits of the non-fixed points?