# Number of orbits for the action of G on the field with 9 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

This question has an answer here but It's not clear to me.
[computing the orbits for a group action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190589/computing-the-orbits-for-a-group-action)

So, I am asking it again.

> Let G be the galois group of a field with 9 elementsover its subfield with 3 elements. Then the number of orbits for the action of G on  the field with 9 elements is?

I want to ask which result in Galois theory should be used. I have studied galois theory but couldn't solve problems due to lack of time. SO, Assume knowledge of graduate text of galois theory while answering it and kindly provide a bit detailed reasoning.

I am really struck so I am asking .
Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) $|\mathbb{F}_9:\mathbb{F}_3|=2$ so by the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory [but we scarcely need it] the Galois Group $G$ has order $2$.

(ii) $\pi: x\mapsto x^3$ is an automorphism of order $2$, so the Galois group is $\langle \pi\rangle$.

(iii) The multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_9$ is cyclic of order $8$. [Clearly the multiplicative group of a field can't have finite non-cyclic subgroups, or we'd contradict the fact that the polynomial ring is a UFD.] Let $\theta$ be a generator.

(iv) Calculate the orbits: they are $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$,$\{-1\}$, $\{\theta, \theta^3 \}$, $\{\theta^{-1}, \theta^{-3}\}$, $\{\theta^{2},\theta^{-2}\}$.

Comment: Using very slightly more Galois theory, we also know that the elements of the base field are precisely the fixed points, so all other orbits much have order 2.

Comment: @ancientmathematician It may sound  very easy easy to you but can you please tell which result you are using to compute $|\mathbb{F}_9:\mathbb{F}_3|=2$? I can't recollect how to find it and don;t wanna memorize it?

Comment: A vector space of dimension $k$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ clearly has $p^k$ elements.

Comment: @ancientmathematician how does π has order 2?

Comment: Oh come on, because $\pi^2(x)=x$.